# read data from file into array of structures

Tags: c, file, structure

Hi I'm trying to read data from file into array of structures I tried to use fgets but got the error saying that RECORD type cannot be convert to char* this is what i have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NAME   20
#define FILE_NAME  50
#define LIST_SIZE 50
//void getData(RECORD name[], RECORD score)


typedef struct RECORD
{
    char *name;
    float  score;
}RECORD;


int main (void)
{
    // Declarations
       FILE *fp;
       char fileName[FILE_NAME];
       RECORD list[LIST_SIZE];
       int count = 0;
    // Statements
       printf("Enter the file name: ");
       gets(fileName);

       fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

       if(fp == NULL)
           printf("Error cannot open the file!\n");
         while (fgets(list[count], LIST_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
         {
             count++;
         }
       return 0;
}
```

the error occurs in the fgets statement inside while loop, how can i fix this and read data into array of structures?

thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
while(fgets((char *)list[count], SIZE/* data size to be read */, fp) != NULL)
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

fgets is used to input a string from a text file one line as a unit.

e.g.)

```
char input_line_buff[128];
fgets(input_line_buff, 128, fp);
```

read-in

input_line_buff:(contents eg) "name 66.6\n"

you do split , memory alloc and copy, and convert .

e.g.)

```
list[count].name = strdup("name");
list[count].score= atof("66.6");
count++;
```